# Reusable and cacheable xaml styles in windows 8 phone

Tags: styles, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8, i want to know that Is there any reusable style xaml functionality available in windows 8 phone.For example i have created two style xaml tag with two different unique key.Then how would i apply that styles to only one element(say one textbox).

Can you please suggest some best style guide website and books, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can define your styles in a number of places:

- The xaml file where it will be used - in the Resource of a parent element.
- The App.xaml file - in the Application.Resources element.
- A dedicated xaml file for the style - this can then be referenced in App.xaml using the **ResourceDictionary** and **ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries** elements.

Wherever you decide to put your style, it will need to be inside a **Resource** element.  If you want your styles to be global, App.xaml is a good choice, e.g.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle2" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
    </Style>
    ...
</Application.Resources>
```

This style can then be referenced as a static resource, as shown below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="Default Style" />
    <TextBox Text="Custom Style" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

You can get really fancy with your styles and define them in their own xaml files and reference them in App.xaml as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Styles">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This can be a really useful way of organising your styles.